# I am creating checkboxlist dynamically , but it showing syntax errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
if (control == 'CheckBoxList2') {                  
        <div class='container'>
              <input type='checkpro1'/>0037 : Quinn, Thomas DDS <br/>
              <input type='checkpro2'/>1234 : Sad, Asd <br/>
              <input type='checkpro3'/>QADR2 : Snell, Jason <br/>
              <input type='checkpro4'/>12SPAC : Space, Ken <br/>
              <input type='checkpro5'/>12345 : Test, Hygienist DDS <br />                
       </div></td></tr>
}
```

It showing red lines in the above code..

I apppend the code in html var but still not working.

if (control == 'CheckBoxList2') {
                    var html_val="
                          0037 : Quinn, Thomas DDS 
                          1234 : Sad, Asd 
                          QADR2 : Snell, Jason 
                          12SPAC : Space, Ken 
                          12345 : Test, Hygienist DDS 
";

```
                </div>
            }
```

Comment: i guess you want `type="checkbox" name="checkproX"`

Comment: You're adding `html` code in js, you'll need to wrap this as a string and then append it where you want.

Comment: I changed type=checkbox but still showing red lines

Answer (score 1):

```
if (control == 'CheckBoxList2') {                  
    var html_val = "<div class='container'><input type='checkbox' name='checkpro1'/>0037 : Quinn, Thomas DDS <br/>";
}
```

Type must be checkbox and name as per your requirement.

Above is the reference code you need to modify as per your requirement.

Append html string in variable and use variable to display the HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can't use HTML like this way in js. Use like this code

```
if (control == 'CheckBoxList2') {                  
    var html_val = "<div class='container'><input type='checkpro1'/>0037 : Quinn, Thomas DDS <br/>";              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the HTML code inside the control with id='CheckBoxList2'

```
if (control == 'CheckBoxList2') {                  
        var divHtml='<div class='container'>';
        divHtml+='<input type='checkpro1'/>0037 : Quinn, Thomas DDS <br/>';
        divHtml+='<input type='checkpro2'/>1234 : Sad, Asd <br/>';
        divHtml+='<input type='checkpro3'/>QADR2 : Snell, Jason <br/>';
        divHtml+='<input type='checkpro4'/>12SPAC : Space, Ken <br/>';
        divHtml+='<input type='checkpro5'/>12345 : Test, Hygienist DDS <br />';                
        divHtml+='</div>';
        document.getElementById('CheckBoxList2').innerHTML=divHtml;
}
```

if you want the HTML code inside another element, say a table cell then you need to reference that element and use innerHTML on that element.